# Installing MAMP on a computer that has MySql installed and a PHP setup on the localhost?

Tags: php, mysql, mamp

I have a macbook running macOS High Sierra(version 10.13.2) on which I would like to install MAMP. On this machine I already have installed MySql(version 5.7.19 homebrew) using brew and set up a php(version 7.1.7) web development environment on the local host. If I install MAMP now would this affect the current MySql I have on the computer now and would it affect the php environment setup on the local host in anyway? Also, would this cause any complications with the MAMP installation?

I just want a clean install that is not gonna cause any problems to my current setup and also to the new setup.

Comment: I believe so. If you wish to have something clean and more powerful, please try [Scotch Box](https://box.scotch.io/) - I am using it and it's super awesome.

Comment: I know that WAMP uses a completely isolated version of both PHP and MySQL. I'd assume MAMP does the same.

Comment: That is what the MAMP documentation says but I'm curious to see if anyone had any issues with this.

Comment: They are separated. Just use different ports for the services. As for CLI, I think your homebrew PHP will be in your PATH already, so if you want to use the MAMP php CLI use the full path like /Applications/MAMP/ etc or create an alias in your bash profile.

Comment: I wrote something sensible for your case, which is the same case as mine. Think about it @Pending...

Comment: I'll consider Scotch Box. Thanks @PraveenKumar !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I install MAMP now would this affect the current MySql I have on the computer now and would it affect the php environment setup on the local host in anyway?

**No**

MAMP is designed to wrap all the "web application stack" (Apache, php, mySql, etc...) into the application package. So installing MAMP you won't touch what's already installed via brew.

Of course you cannot run simultaneously MAMP's mySql+Apache and brew-installed mySql+*(web server of your choice)* (unless -of course- you setup a proper custom configuration).

Comment: I didn't think it would but I wanted to reassure myself. Thank you!